# Backup of Postgresql database with pg_dump

Tags: java, database, postgresql, pg-dump

after a search on the internet with no result, I turn to you!
I would like to create a java program, that if you click on a button, it makes a backup of a database in postgresql.
I saw that i must use pg_dump but do not understand how to make it work.
can someone please help me?

thank you!

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: do you know how the use pg_dump from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use an OS command inside a Java program, make this (with vivek answer):

```
public class Backup{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
        final String cmd = "pg_dump  --format=c --username \"postgres\" db_name > \"D:\\pgBackup\\db_name.backup\"";

        java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
        java.lang.Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Runtime` to execute the command that you use to execute the command that you would normally use to backup your database from the console interface.